# Tsql setting string variable across multiple lines

Tags: t-sql, syntax

This is real weird.
when I trace through this code, on the first statement, I am getting @str as a valid insert statement when it is coded as a single line, but when I set @str through select statement, accross multiple lines, it holds value of nothing.

Its really flakey, because some of my inserts worked, and some didn't.

Any ideas how to set the variable properly across multiple lines?  Or is this a Microsoft bug...?

UPDATE:  Same thing happens when I edit the multi-line t-sql Select into a one line statement
@str, when tracing the code, often turns out to be blank, when it seems like it should not be blank...(the second instance of @str...
      Select @str = 'Insert into CustShip Values (' + '''' + @A_Cust_No + '''' + ', ' + '''' +  @Ship_To_Id + '''' + ',3)'
       EXEC(@str)
       Select @str = 'Insert into ShipTo Values ....'
This Second @str is often evaluated to blank....)

```
ALTER Procedure [dbo].[RefreshCustShip3]
AS
Begin   /* Begin Proc */
Set NoCount On

--Delete from CustShip

    DECLARE @SHIP_TO_NAME  VarChar(255),
            @A_Cust_No varchar(255),
            @SHIP_TO_ADD1 VarChar(255),
            @SHIP_TO_ADD2 VarChar(255),
            @SHIP_TO_ADD3 VarChar(255),
            @CITY VarChar(255),
            @STAT VarChar(255),
            @ZIP_Code VarChar(255),
            @SHIP_TO_ID VarChar(255),
            @COUNTRY VarChar(255),
            @ShipId varchar(255),
            @str varchar(1000)

    DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD /* read only, forward only */ FOR
    SELECT 
    A#CUST#NO, 
    CUST#NAME as SHIP#TO#NAME, 
    SOLD#TO#ADD#1 AS SHIP#TO#ADD#1, 
    SOLD#TO#ADD#2 AS SHIP#TO#ADD2, 
    SOLD#TO#ADD#3 AS SHIP#TO#ADD3, 
    SOLD#TO#CITY AS CITY, 
    SOLD#TO#STATE AS [STATE], 
    SOLD#TO#ZIP#CODE AS ZIP#CODE, 
    CONCAT(LTRIM(RTRIM(A#CUST#NO)), LTRIM(RTRIM(SOLD#TO#ADD#1))) AS SHIP#TO#ID, 
    COUNTRY#NAME as Country 
    from Cust left join CustShip on 
    Cust.A#Cust#No = CustShip.CustNo 
    WHERE CustShip.ShipToID is Null

    OPEN C

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @A_Cust_No, @Ship_To_Name, @SHIP_TO_ADD1, @SHIP_TO_ADD2, @SHIP_TO_ADD3, @CITY, @STAT, @ZIP_Code, @SHIP_TO_ID, @Country;

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

        if @A_Cust_No = '3RGHOU' 
        begin
            print @Ship_To_Id
        end

    -- do work here BEGIN CODE BLOCK
       Select @str = 'Insert into CustShip Values (' + '''' + @A_Cust_No + '''' + ', ' + '''' +  @Ship_To_Id + '''' + ',3)'
       EXEC(@str)
       Select @str = 'Insert into ShipTo Values (' + '''' + @A_Cust_No + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Name + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Add1 + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Add2 + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Add3 + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @City + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @Stat + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @ZIP_Code + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @Ship_To_Id + '''' + ', '
       + '''' +  @Country + ''''       
       + ',3)'
       EXEC(@str)


        FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @A_Cust_No, @Ship_To_Name, @SHIP_TO_ADD1, @SHIP_TO_ADD2, @SHIP_TO_ADD3, @CITY, @STAT, @ZIP_Code, @SHIP_TO_ID, @Country;
    End

    CLOSE C;

    DEALLOCATE C;

End     /* End Proc */


GO
```

Comment: If you have a `null` in there, you'll get a `null` out. Try wrapping the variables with `Coalesce( @Ship_To_Name, '' )`, ... . Aside: It might be easier to read if you created a variable for a quotation mark, e.g. `declare @Quote as Char(1) = '''';`, and use that as needed. `declare @QuoteComma as Char(2) = @Quote + ',';` might not hurt, too.

Comment: if you post Coalesce as an answer, i will mark it as the answer.  if not, I will give Rob the credit.  I edited his post to include your answer.

Comment: Aside: It isn't clear what you are actually trying to accomplish. The code you posted seems to be performing what could be done by two `insert ... select ...` statements that copy data from one table to another. You've also created a [SQL Injection](http://bobby-tables.com/) opportunity by not using parameters with [`execute`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/execute-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). And the best practice for `insert` is to provide a column list, e.g. `insert into CustShip ( CustNo ) values ( @CustNo );`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm thinking out loud here. From looking at your SQL, Is there a possibility that you're running past your limit of VARCHAR(1000) on @Str? You're creating a string that has 10 variables that each could contain 255 characters. That is a total of 2550 characters without your insert statement syntax.

Also, since you're just assign that string to a single variable you should use SET instead of SELECT.

Also, put a semicolon statement terminator after the end of the string before the EXEC statement.

Also as HABO said above a null value in any of those variables would null out the entire string. Coalesce or doing `ISNULL(@CITY, '')` would fix that.

Comment: that could very well explain the inconsistency and flakiness.  it would be better if it just crashed than to evaluate it as nothing....  i will check it out...

Comment: Also as HABO said above a null value in any of those variables would null out the entire string. Coalesce or doing ISNULL(@CITY, '') would fix that.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is best answer, though many thanks to other posters who lead me to the trail.  They deserve credit.  Not sure if there is way to give them credit or not....

```
   -- do work here BEGIN CODE BLOCK
       Select @str = 'Insert into CustShip Values (' + '''' + @A_Cust_No + '''' + ', ' + '''' +  @Ship_To_Id + '''' + ',3)'
       EXEC(@str)
       Select @str2 = 'Insert into ShipTo Values (' + 
       iif(@A_Cust_No is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@A_Cust_No,'''','''''') + '''') 
       + ', ' + 
       iif(@Ship_To_Name is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@Ship_To_Name,'''','''''') + '''') + ', ' + 
       iif(@Ship_To_Add1 is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@Ship_To_Add1,'''','''''') + '''') + ', ' + 
       iif(@Ship_To_Add2 is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@Ship_To_Add2,'''','''''') + '''') + ', ' + 
       iif(@Ship_To_Add3 is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@Ship_To_Add3,'''','''''') + '''') + ', ' + 
       iif(@City is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@City,'''','''''') + '''') + ', ' + 
       iif(@Stat is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@Stat,'''','''''') + '''') + ', ' + 
       iif(@Zip_Code is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@Zip_Code,'''','''''') + '''') + ', ' + 
       iif(@Ship_To_Id is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@Ship_To_Id,'''','''''') + '''') + ', ' + 
       iif(@Country is Null, 'Null', '''' + Replace(@Country,'''','''''') + '''') + ', 3)' 

       EXEC(@str2)


        FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @A_Cust_No, @Ship_To_Name, @SHIP_TO_ADD1, @SHIP_TO_ADD2, @SHIP_TO_ADD3, @CITY, @STAT, @ZIP_Code, @SHIP_TO_ID, @Country;
    End
```